# Convert Unix path to DOS path

Tags: unix, shell, string, dos, ksh

I have a variable that stores a Unix path, for example:

```
typeset unixpath=/foo/bar/
```

And I have to convert it to a DOS path using KornShell (ksh) scripting:

```
dospath=\\\\foo\\\\bar\\\\
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
dospath=`echo $unixpath | sed 's/\//\\\\/g'`
```

<sub>Thanks to [David Wolever](https://stackoverflow.com/users/71522/david-wolever) for reminding me to use a $ to access the value of the variable!</sub>

Comment: I'm no korn expert, but I think that needs a '$' somewhere...  Anyway, that's exactly how I'd do it, if you hadn't posted first.

Comment: It depends whether eleven81 meant: echo /unix/path or echo $unixpath; either could be valid.

Answer (score 1):

If you have *ksh93*:

```
ksh-M 93t 2008-11-04$ unixpath=/foo/bar/            
ksh-M 93t 2008-11-04$ print ${unixpath//\//\\\\\\\\}
\\foo\\bar\\
```

Answer (score 1):

The AT&T ksh93 for Windows allows you to tag variables for automatic conversion with
'typeset -H':

$ typeset -H home=$HOME && print $home=$HOME
C:\users\Henk=/home/Henk

Answer (score 0):

I would have added as a comment to eleven81's answer, but I don't have the points

to make it slightly more readable, how about using an alternative sed delimiter

i.e.

```
dospath=`echo $unixpath | sed 's./.\\\\.g'`
```